# Volleyball Hitting Stat Clarification

Tags: statistics, volleyball

If a hitter hits the ball out-of-bounds, but the opposing blocker is call for net violation before the ball lands out-of-bounds, does the hitter get both an attempt and a hitting error recorded or does the blocking error wipe out the attempt and hitting error?